# Powershell Core can't execute Cmdlet that Powershell can

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, powershell-core

When I try to execute `Resolve-DnsName google.de` in a Powershell Core (Version 7.3.5) I get the error

```
Resolve-DnsName: The 'Resolve-DnsName' command was found in the module 'DnsClient', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error: [Cannot process Cmdlet Definition XML for the following file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\MSFT_DnsClient.cdxml. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.Cim.CimCmdletAdapter, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".]
For more information, run 'Import-Module DnsClient'.
```

When I run `Import-Module DnsClient` I just get mostly the same error

```
Import-Module: Cannot process Cmdlet Definition XML for the following file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\MSFT_DnsClient.cdxml. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.Cim.CimCmdletAdapter, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
```

However, when I run the same command in a Windwows Powershell (Version 5.1.22621.1778), I get no error, but the correct output.

Why does this differenc in behavior happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the question (if any)?

Comment: cool people use `nslookup`

Comment: This is a PowerShell profile issue.  PowerShell 7.x and PowerShell 5.1 can be installed side-by-side. However, they use different PowerShell profiles.  The fact PowerShell is trying to load a module from he folder it's attempting to do so suggests a PowerShell profile issue. It's no longer called "PowerShell Core" by the way.  PowerShell Core essentially replaced PowerShell 5.1 4 years ago, but PowerShell 5.1 is still the built-in version for a variety of reasons.

Comment: "PowerShell Core" is open source and runs on .NET Core and is more intended for use on servers. It is distinct from "Windows PowerShell" which runs on the full .NET Framework. You might prefer to use the "Windows PowerShell" variant.

Comment: @Gantendo `nslookup` is not working corretly with our setup (I don't know why), but if I use `ping` or `Resolve-DnsName` to resolve an company internal domain name it gives the correct IP, but `nslookup` does not

Comment: @harrymc I actually prefer to use the "Powershell Core" on my PC, because then the scripts that I create work (in principle) in all enviroments that have a pwsh (like servers, build agents, ...)

Comment: @Ramhound what would you suggest how I can solve this problem

Comment: Try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686868/17660).